# How to change the colour of a point of graph in pgfplots depending on y axis value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to write some tikz code so that a graph can be repeated several times in a document, and keep consistent formatting.

All was going well until I decided I want to change the colour of the points depending on the values entered in "\myGraph".

All values above 5 should appear red, all values below 5 should be green.

The best I could come up with is below, I think the code I've written effectively makes all values above the halfway point (of the min/max data values) red, and below green. So for some situations it's ok, but for others it's not.

I need to change the line

```
\ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt<500pt
```

to something like

```
\ifdim\pgfplotspointmeta pt<5
```

but this doesn't work. Is anyone able to help?

Many thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\newcommand{\myGraph}[3]
{   
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[
scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
    \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt<500pt
        \def\markopts{fill=green}%
    \else
        \def\markopts{fill=red}
     \fi
    \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
},%
 scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
     \endscope
 },enlargelimits=0.1,ymin=0,ymax=10,/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}]
\addplot[scatter, line width=3pt, black,dashed, mark=*, mark options=     {scale=4,solid}] coordinates {%
(2017, #1)
(2019, #2) 
(2021, #3)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
First points should be green (2017,2019), last point should be red (2021).
\myGraph{1}{2}{7}

First point and last should be red (2017,2021), middle point should be green    (2019).

\myGraph{9}{4}{9}

But ... 

\myGraph{7}{7}{8}

all points should be red. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by simply using a mathematical function that you provide to the `point meta` key and defining a custom `colormap` that consists of the colors you need.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\myGraph}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            enlargelimits=0.1,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=10,
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
            % create custom colorbar for the two colors you need
            colormap={my colormap}{
                color=(green)
                color=(red)
            },
        ]
            \addplot [
                scatter,
                line width=3pt,
                black,
                dashed,
                mark=*,
                mark options={scale=4,solid},
                % ---
                % apply here the function you need for the meta data
                point meta={ifthenelse(y>5,1,0)},
                % ... and set the limits of the `point meta' data (by hand)
                % (the automatic approach doesn't work if only 1 value is
                %  present which is the case for the third example)
                point meta min=0,
                point meta max=1,
            ] coordinates {
                (2017, #1)
                (2019, #2)
                (2021, #3)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \myGraph{1}{2}{7}
    \myGraph{9}{4}{9}
    \myGraph{7}{7}{8}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]